# Newtonsoft JSON/JSON.NET custom serialization - System.Object members not correctly deserialized even when setting TypeNameHandling

Tags: c#, types, json.net, json-serialization

I'm trying to implement custom serialization using Newtonsoft.Json where I want all fields serialized, and then deserialized to their proper types. The class contains a field of type "object", implements `ISerializable`, has a `[Serializable]` attribute set, and has a serialization constructor. I set the value of this object field to an instance of some class, then serialize it. I use a `JsonSerializer` with `TypeNameHandling` set to `TypeNameHandling.Auto`.

Here's the code that I'm trying out:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        [Serializable]
        class Foobar : ISerializable
        {
            public Foobar()
            {
            }

            public Foobar(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            {
                something = info.GetValue("something", typeof(object));
            }

            public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            {
                info.AddValue("something", something);
            }

            public object Something { get { return something; } set { something = value; } }
            private object something;

            [JsonIgnore]
            private string someOtherObject = "foobar";
        }

        class SomeOtherClass
        {
            public string Foo { get; set; }
            public string Bar { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foobar myObj = new Foobar();

            myObj.Something = new SomeOtherClass() { Bar = "My first", Foo = "fqwkifjwq" };

            var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
            serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
            serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            string serialized;
            using (var tw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(tw))
                    serializer.Serialize(jw, myObj);

                tw.Flush();
                serialized = tw.ToString();
            }

            Foobar deserialized;
            using (var rt = new StringReader(serialized))
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(rt))
                deserialized = serializer.Deserialize<Foobar>(jsonReader);

            Console.WriteLine("Type of deserialized.Something: " + deserialized.Something.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

After deserialization, the field `Foobar.Something` is simply a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`, which is NOT what I want. I would like this to be properly deserialized to an object of type `SomeOtherClass`. The serialized output does contain the required info:

```
{
  "something": {
    "$type": "ConsoleApp1.Program+SomeOtherClass, ConsoleApp1",
    "Foo": "fqwkifjwq",
    "Bar": "My first"
  }
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Using the code above. Does exactly how I describe above.
2. Using the `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.Fields)]` attribute on the object I'm serializing. Then I get an object of the correct type on the `Foobar.Something` field (a `SomeOtherClass` instance), BUT, any non-serialized fields with a default value gets initialized to null instead of their default value (like the field `Foobar.someOtherObject`).
3. Removing the `Serializable` attribute. Then the `ISerializable GetObjectData` and the serialization constructor is not called.
4. Setting the JsonSerializer's `TypeNameHandling` property to `All` (no effect).

So - any tips on how this can be solved?

Comment: By default, Json.Net will serialize all public properties.  You can make it serialize/deserialize specific private fields if you add a [JsonProperty] attribute to the field.  It doesn't look like you are doing anything custom inside the serialization constructor or `GetObjectData`, so unless I'm missing something I don't think you need to implement `ISerializable` nor use the `[Serializable]` attribute.  If you just make `Foobar` a plain c# object it seems to work as expected.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/0e1uGM.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The actual use case I have is to serialize and deserialize a rather huge and complex data structure, where what I need to serialize is not neccessarily only public. It's legacy code, and the amount of fields and properties present makes it impractical to add the [JsonPropery] attribute to every field that I need to serialize. It's also not practical to make proper public properties out of them all.

So I figure I'll serialize all fields (I do it by getting all fields through reflection in GetObjectData/ctor). It works 99%. However, the specific scenario in my question does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, to summarize your question/comments:

1. You have a huge and complex legacy data structure which you would like to serialize and deserialize.
2. Much of the data you want to de/serialize is in private fields and it is too cumbersome to add attributes to those or add public properties.
3. Some of those fields are of type `object` and you want to preserve the type of those values for the round trip.
4. Some of those fields are expressly marked to be ignored for serialization purposes and they have default values which you would like to keep.
5. You tried using `TypeNameHandling.Auto` and implementing `ISerializable`; this worked for serialization (the child object type was written to the JSON) but did not work for deserialization (you got a `JObject` back instead of the actual child object instance).
6. You tried using `TypeNameHandling.Auto` and marking your outer class with `MemberSerialization.Fields`; this worked for serialization, but on deserialization you lost the default values for your ignored fields.

Let's look at both approaches and see what we can do.

### ISerializable

It does seem a bit odd that Json.Net does not respect the `TypeNameHandling.Auto` setting on deserialization for child objects of `ISerializable` when it does write the type information for those into the JSON on serialization.  I don't know whether this is a bug, an oversight, or if there some technical limitation in play here.  Regardless, it does not behave as expected.

However, you may be able to implement a workaround.  Since you do get a `JObject` back in the `SerializationInfo`, and that `JObject` has the `$type` string in it, you could make an extension method which will create your child object from the `JObject` based on the `$type`:

```
public static class SerializationInfoExtensions
{
    public static object GetObject(this SerializationInfo info, string name)
    {
        object value = info.GetValue(name, typeof(object));
        if (value is JObject)
        {
            JObject obj = (JObject)value;
            string typeName = (string)obj["$type"];
            if (typeName != null)
            {
                Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
                if (type != null)
                {
                    value = obj.ToObject(type);
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then, use it in your serialization constructor in place of `GetValue` whenever the type is `object`:

```
public Foobar(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    something = info.GetObject("something");
}
```

### MemberSerialization.Fields

It looks like using `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.Fields)]` attribute does mostly what you want except for losing the default values on some of your ignored properties.  It turns out that Json.Net intentionally does not call the normal constructor when using `MemberSerialization.Fields`-- instead it uses the [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject?view=netframework-4.8) method to create a *completely* empty object before populating the fields from the JSON.  This obviously will prevent your default values from getting initialized.

To work around this, you can use a custom `ContractResolver` to replace the object creation function, e.g.:

```
class FieldsOnlyResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        contract.DefaultCreator = () => Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, true);
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Note: the above assumes all your objects will have default (parameterless) constructors.  If this is not the case, you can either add them where needed (they can be private), or change the resolver to supply a different creator function depending on the type.

To use it, just add the resolver to your `JsonSerializer` instance:

```
serializer.ContractResolver = new FieldsOnlyResolver();
```

Comment: First off - you summarized the problem perfectly. And this would indeed solve my problem! Thank you for a very helpful and tidy answer to my question!

Since most of our classes already implements ISerializable, I'll probably go for the solution you gave here. The other solution sure will come in handy another rainy day. :-)

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but as I have just been wrestling with this myself recently and have already found a solution prior to coming across this, I wanted to point out an alternative to changing the contract resolver. If you add a `JsonConstructorAttribute` to a constructor in the class it will use it, even when `MemberSerialization` is set to `Fields`